# Get renamed Filename in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to get renamed filename in PHP? I'm trying this code, but it's not giving me .ext I think there is a problem with my explode command. Can any one help me please?

Here is my code

```
$target = '..\img\web\users'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

if ( 0 < $_FILES['file']['error'] ) {
    echo 'Error: ' . $_FILES['file']['error'] . '<br>';
}else{
    $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $newfilename = $user['email'] . '.' . end($temp);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target . $newfilename);

    $q = "UPDATE users SET img ='$newfilename' WHERE email = '$user[email]'";
    $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

}
```

After that, its gives me $newfilename = 'uploaded-file.'  in my sql table there is no extension. Where is my extension :))

I'm trying to upload image file, changing it with user email adress.

EDIT: My input is like that / and jquery:

```
<img id="img" alt="User Pic" <?php if($user['img'] == ''){ echo 'src="img/web/user.png"'; }else{ echo 'src="img/web/users/'.$user['img'].'"'; } ?>  class="img-circle img-responsive" style="border:1px solid red; min-width:150px; min-height:150px; max-width:150px; max-height:150px;"><br />
<input id="avatar" name="file" type="file" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" style="padding:0px; margin:0px;" autocomplete="off"  accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg">

$('#save_details').on('click', function() {
    var file_data = $('#avatar').prop('files')[0];   
    var form_data = new FormData();                  
    form_data.append('file', file_data);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'admin/useredit.php', // point to server-side PHP script 
        dataType: 'text',  // what to expect back from the PHP script, if anything
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: form_data,                         
        type: 'post'

     });
});
```

var_dump of $_FILES:

```
array(1) { 
    ["file"]=> array(5) { 
        ["name"]=> string(9) "index.jpg" 
        ["type"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" 
        ["tmp_name"]=> string(24) "C:\xampp\tmp\php7489.tmp" 
        ["error"]=> int(0) 
        ["size"]=> int(4465) 
    } 
}
```

Comment: I'm kinda supprised it didn't work, look ok on paper to me (without me runing it/testing it)

Comment: Does move_uploaded_file works as expected? Mabye the 'img' colomn isn't big enough?

Comment: Actually, its gives me errors like undefined index: file, undefined index:name  etc. But uploading also. I'm using jquery file upload (via ajax)

Comment: var_dump($newfilename);
gives me : string(23) "pervinozyedi@gmail.com." 
in the end you can see there is point "." but not extension

Comment: @IncredibleHat i'm edited my post. I have contentype:false also..

Comment: @sanderbee yes move_uploaded_file working clearly. Its moving my file to target directory.

Comment: @IncredibleHat var_dump($_FILES);   -- >


array(1) { ["file"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(9) "index.jpg" ["type"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" ["tmp_name"]=> string(24) "C:\xampp\tmp\php7489.tmp" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(4465) } }

Comment: I'm really baffled how it gives you errors about undefined indexes... yet saves the file... yet does not grab the extension after the last dot. Something really crazy is going on, and nothing I see in your code suggests why :(

Comment: @IncredibleHat  Mee too. But it's interesting: if i write echo $newfilename; its gives me renamed file name and extension :) but if i use it in query, it's not gives me .extension. So weird

Comment: Maybe i have problem with my query; as you know, mail adress like user@domain.com...  if i want to change it with image name; it will be user@domain.com.jpg    Maybe there is some mistake with .com.ext part. But i'm not sure

Comment: So the image saves, echoing out the new filename is correct ... except the database field itself is missing the extension? I guess what @sanderbee asked comes into play: maybe the 'img' column isn't big enough? Also, is it a standard varchar field, or text, or something else entirely?

Comment: in my mysql database : img column is varchar --> Length is 200. i think its enough

Comment: `"UPDATE users SET img ='$newfilename' WHERE email = '$user[email]'"` ... if that works at all, should work. The email field would be sketchy since the variable use is wrong... but the img field should be exactly as you see in the echo. If you use a prepared statement, it may work better. But the errors and situations you have described... cannot all be happening together (if indexes are undefined error, there is no possible way it can use values in those undefined indexes). Sorry... I'm out of ideas at this point :(

Answer (score 0):

I was going to make this a comment but it became too long, so I'll write it like an answer and *hope* I'm correct:

What appears to be happening is that you have another call happening elsewhere to that edit URL that does not have an image attached at the `file` index.

There's a couple of ways this could happen off hand:

1. Maybe you're not preventing the normal submit after your ajax call and the normal submit is sent again but with the wrong form encoding? (If your page is refreshing after clicking that button - this may well be what's happening.)
2. you have other ajax calls to this same script setting other user
   properties, but not the avatar image.
3. *Addendum:* Other bugs could do it too, take a look at your network activity in your browser's inspection console/dev tools.

If I'm right - the following should prevent what you're seeing from occurring:

```
if(!empty($_FILES['file'])) {

    if ( 0 < $_FILES['file']['error'] ) {
        echo 'Error: ' . $_FILES['file']['error'] . '<br>';
    }else{
        $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
        $newfilename = $user['email'] . '.' . end($temp);
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target . $newfilename);

        $q = "UPDATE users SET img ='$newfilename' WHERE email = '$user[email]'";
        $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
    }
}
```

Again, assuming I'm correct here - in the extra request where you don't send the file `$_FILES['file']['error']` evaluates to `null` (and throws that undefined index warning) and since `(0 < null)` evaluates as `false` it'll run your upload processing and update the user record *even though the file isn't attached in that particular request!*

Adding the non-empty check should prevent you from accidentally overwriting the proper one with an extension-less record.